# Mongosastic query to query on indexed data and filter by date

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have Paper indexed in my elastic index and need to perform a multi match query on it. Query is to be done on an array of names and also an array of ids. My query fetches the result but only on one of the criteria.

```
Paperupload.esSearch({ 
    from:from,
    size:size,
            query:{
                bool:{
                    "must": {
                        "bool" : { "must": [{terms : {"topics.topic_name": topi}}] } 
                    },
                    "must": {
                        "bool" : { "must": [{terms : {"userId._id": followersDetail}}] }
                    },
                    "must_not": {
                        "bool" : { "should": [{terms : {"_id": userPapersId}}] }
                    } 
                }
            },
            sort:{
                "createdAt":{
                    "order" : "desc"
                }
            }   
},
function(err, results) {
}
```

Paperupload is my indexed elastic index. I am performing search on 3 fields and sorting them by the `createdAt` date. my result set is only consist of result based on first condition. I have used NPM mongosastic.

Result should be mixture of all 3 criteria but sorted by `createdAt` date.

Comment: Can you add a document which should have matched query but is not actually coming in results?

Comment: Result set either has result based on condition one or condition 2.But it should had been mixture of both based on Createddate

Comment: Can any one in forum reply to this thread

Comment: You need add [mcve] so that there is a better understanding to the problem.

Comment: Sorry @NishantSaini. The following example is only giving me result based on condition 1.It is not fetching the result of 2nd conditon matches.If I remove the first condtion the result set is list of papers of the people i follow.If I remove the second condtion it will match all my topics which is an array of names and display.While the query should fetch me mixture of the both condition sorted by date.

Comment: Is there any way to search in an indexed collection in elastic with multiple condition.First my array of names with array of indexed topic .And also match my followers with with indexed userId.and also should not fetch my papers that is not equal to my id

Answer (score 0):

```
Paperupload.esSearch({ 
                    query:{
                            bool:{
                                "must": {
                                    "bool" : { "should": [{terms : {"userId._id": followersDetail}},{terms : {"topics.topic_name": topi}}] }
                                }
                            }
                        },          
                        sort:{
                            "createdAt":{
                                "order" : "desc"
                            }
                        }   
                    },
                    {
                        from:from,
                        size:size,
                    },
                    function(err, results) {
})
```

Comment: This will fetch the result in sorted order and multi matches can be done using the same